# how to use htaccess to have a development and production environment on same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to have my dev and production run on the same server. I have an htaccess file that should send you to one or the other. so all urls that are www.website.com/dev/... send you to the development folder. all other urls send you to the production folder.

The production works fine.

The development side doesn't work when I use seo friendly URLS.

www.website.com/dev/index.php   (works)

www.website.com/dev/register/   (doesn't work)

Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

#don't let them access the .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

#don't let people refer to our pictures
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?website.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.website.com/index.php [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(dev/)(.*) devFolder/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ productionFolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.website.com/index.html [NC,L]
```

In each of the sub folders there is a .htaccess file and they are both identical. here is an example of what the rewrite code looks like inside those.

```
#registration
RewriteRule ^[rR]egister$ register_login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[rR]egistered$ register_login.php [L]
```

Comment: Why don't you define a development virtual host with a seperate subdomain (so you can keep all urls after the domain the same)?

Comment: Do you have htaccess files in the dev folder and production folder?

Comment: yes I do have .htaccess in both the dev and production folder. they are currently the same. I'll put examples in the question

Comment: I tried and if I change the rewrite rules in the dev .htaccess to RewriteRule ^[rR]egister$ dev/register_login.php [L], things then work properly. Is there a way to do this once at the top or do I have to do it for each entry?

Comment: RewriteBase /dev/   in the dev sub folder .htaccess seems to solve my problems.

Comment: @JonLin your comment led to the answer so if you write it up I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me.

In the root folder

```
RewriteRule ^(dev/)(.*) devFolder/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ productionFolder/$1 [L]
```

in the sub folders the .htaccess files are identical except for the rewrite base in the dev folder

```
RewriteBase /dev/
```